# send get or post php data to server on button click android

Tags: php, android, post, get

**I want pass post or get data from android on button click to php server, without using browser.**
for eg 
*http://localhost:81/anis/car.php?name=xyz*
is data i want to pass on button click. without using browser.

Comment: have you try anything also look here how to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localhost - it search host on device on which you are running.
Replace localhost to your ip. Surely it will work.

Comment: how to call that url in android on button click event.?

Comment: You can use HttpClient or Volley Library for this.